# выскакивает ошибка 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа

```py
import random
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(random.randint(-100, 100))


mean_ =[]
max_ = []
min_ = []
for i in a:
  if i > 0:
    pass
print((sum(i) / len(i)))
```

условие: напечатать среднее арифметическое всех положительных чисел из списка a

Comment: `len(i)`..........

Comment: Да тут вообще не приступали к заданию...

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы даете команду найти длину объекта класса int и сумму объекта также класса int, что невозможно. Исправьте в последней строке строке в двух скобках i на a

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(random.randint(-100, 100))`
mean_ =[]
max_ = []
min_ = []
for i in a:
  if i > 0:
    pass
print((sum(i) / len(i)))
```

Comment: Не поможет решить задачу, `a` будет содержать отрицательные значения. Здесь ошибка глубже. Тот же самый код и с теми же ошибками

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(random.randint(-100, 100))
print(a)
a = [i for i in a if i > 0]
print(a)
print( sum(a) / len(a) )
```

Но Вам стоит изучить что-нибудь по основам